# Dial PPPoE connection on Windows startup

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, boot, pppoe

Is there a way to automatically dial a PPPoE connection on startup? In Mac OS X, this is done automatically after login. It was also possible in Windows XP: when creating a new connection, it also created a shortcut to it on the desktop. Adding it to the startup folder and setting it to not prompt for credentials solved the problem.

But in Vista and Windows 7, there are no shortcuts to the newly created connections, so I can't do the same thing here. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On **Vista**,

1. Open Control Panel

   - Network and share center
   - Manage Network Connections
   - Drag-and-drop dial-up connection to the startup folder

Something similar should be do-able on **Windows 7** too.

Answer (score 4):

this also requires "Prompt for name and password..." to be cleared in the connection properties.

imho, it's better to use a router configured for your PPPoE connection.

Comment: Right now I have a router that connects me automatically, but my parents don't. I don't like the fact that they have to take an extra step to connect to the internet every time they just want to check their email.

Comment: how do your parents connect to the internet? can't you connect their computer to the router as well?

Comment: They live somewhere else :). So, no router for them. They only have one desktop computer, so a router seems pointless.

Comment: Motto!  SuperUser.com: We don't *all* live in our parents' basement.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 7 create new task in scheduler which executes on logon.
Action is  `rasdial.exe "MyPppoeName" "Username" "Password"`
Use full path to rasdial.exe if you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 too has shortcut to network which you can drop in startup folder.
It is located in "Change adapter settings" link in Network an sharing center.
I really don't know why Microsoft put a link to Network in Adapter setting tab but it indeed is there.

Answer (score 1):

I made this utility that will help people with PPPOE connection automatically connect on startup or keep the internet active.

Download from here: [Auto PPOE for Windows 10](http://www.games-shark.com/auto-PPPOE-for-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

This shows in part the value of a router, even for one PC only.  The non-Windows, off-disk firewall should also add to the value of a router even for one PC.